# TFS Query from Backlog created differentlly

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am creating a query from the backlog in 2 different TFS projects using the link on the backlog page:
[image]

It is generating differently for each project. 
The 1st project was created in TFS2103 and upgraded to 2015:
[image]

The 2nd project was created new in TFS 2015 after the upgrade.
[image]

Note the difference in the query for the Area path. The one for the project created before the upgrade uses the 'Under' operator. The one create after the upgrade uses the '=' operator.

Can anyone explain what is causing the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is governed by the Area configuration for your team. You can find it in the Configuration panel:

[image]